# What to do when a suspicious, but potentially useful edit appears?

Tags: discussion, edits

An interesting edit came through the queue today; a user had posted a question with no code, then there was an edit containing the code.

Normally, this is no big deal. People (unfortunately) commonly forget to include relevant code in their posts. However, this one was by a completely different user (hence the inclusion in the review queue). I voted to reject, as did one other reviewer, but we were beaten by some (presumable) robo-reviewers and the edit was accepted.

I flagged the post due to the strange nature of the edit (specifically its source), but I don't know what (if anything) to do in addition. I could roll the edit back, but for all I know it's actually the right code! I wouldn't want to make an edit that is *detrimental* to a post.

Is there a standard operating procedure for this situation?

For context, here is the question where this occurred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335397/stackoverflowexception-when-calling-getcustomattributes

Comment: Check the comments. Sometimes a user will have posted a fiddle or something in the comments, and a helpful user will edit it in.

Comment: @hichris123, Did that before rejecting the edit. Unless it was deleted there were no comments containing code or a fiddle, or anything else to suggest a source for the code provided in the edit.

Comment: ["Fixed grammer"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3341350)

Comment: ^^ Look for edits going in the other direction, too.

Comment: I think its really time to increase the limit of edit review approvals needed

Comment: @BradLarson, is there a quick way of doing this without just going through their activity log? Either way, assuming I found/noticed it ,should I flag additional posts, or just the one I did?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - The one's fine. We can take it from there.

Comment: Someone else added in all the required code?  I think I have finally seen proof of mental telepathy! :O

Comment: It could be two coworkers. _"I've posted the question, can you please add the code we were talking about?"_

Comment: If it useful/non-destructive to the question I don't see any problem.

Comment: I've seen a similiar question some weeks ago. User A asked a question, then user B answered, but user B talked about code that was not part of the question. I asked user B about that in a comment, then one or two minutes later an edit to the question appeared by user A, containing the code user B talked about. When I added another comment to the answer saying that this was quite suspicious, user B deleted his answer.

Comment: @sloth: Wait, but, that would mean... No... Surely there aren't people out there actively trying to game the SE system? Say it ain't so! ;-)

Comment: @DanielDarabos yes, first thing that came to mind was "coworkers!", thanks! Optimism :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that the editor "magically" got the code  from somewhere. It's possible that the OP has multiple accounts, and accidentally used their other account to make the edit. Or the code could be a rip-off from an external forum, posted in an attempt to gain +2 reputation. Or maybe the editor can ... read minds.

It's definitely something that needs to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis. If you're not sure, just flag the post for for moderator attention, and explain the situation using an "Other" flag; they will handle the situation appropriately.

These are some general situations, and the recommended action:

- If you come across such an edit while reviewing, **reject it** as *Vandalism* or *Radical change*.
- If the edit had already been approved, **roll it back** to the previous revision.

However, if the code was posted in the comments section as a link to a pastebin site, JSFiddle, or similar, and it was edited in by someone into the question, you shouldn't flag the post for moderator attention. That is perfectly acceptable behavior, and even encouraged. You should only flag questions which require *a moderator* to take action, not something that the community can handle.

Comment: Right, I had already checked for a link/code comment before flagging, just wasn't sure about the roll-back. Very good advice though!

Answer (score 3):

I've seen that kind of edits and I think there is another posibility: a developer ask a question and then another developer of the same team/project, aware of the issue, completes it by himself instead of waiting for his teammate doing it.

A couple of months ago happened something similar with an old answer I gave more than a year ago: someone upvoted it and added a comment like *"Just what I was looking for!"* and then a couple of upvotes more came in a few minutes... I guess that answer was shared within a team.

What to do in that case? Not sure. If the code seems to fit and it does not seem a vandalic edition, I'd accept it. It does not happen often, so accepting it won't encourage that kind of editions, I think.

Answer (score -2):

The edit being approved in the first place is just ridiculous.  I don't understand how three people could actually approve that edit.

Anyway, I would have rolled it back if the OP had not later edited it.  The OP showed his approval of the edit by choosing to keep it in his post.  He may have thought it must be right because it was approved by reviewers, but he showed his approval nonetheless.

Since the OP approves of the edit, it is not really defacing his post, which is what rolling back is used to prevent (not to say that it wasn't a bad edit in the first place).  Therefore, at this point, the code should remain in the question.

Comment: Adding code that did not exist in the question (when the question isn't yours) is inappropriate. If a "helpful editor" edited to include the code from a jsfiddle or other offsite location, it would appear in the revision history, and it doesn't. The fact the original asker accepted the *gift* of code from another user doesn't make the invalid edit suddenly valid.

Comment: I never said it was valid.  I said it shouldn't be removed.  There's a difference.  The OP clearly thought that the code was relevant to their question and chose to leave it.

Comment: Sorry, but you did. "The OP showed his approval" and "Since the OP approves...it is not really defacing his post", which is wrong. It is in fact defacing the post, and violates guidelines here about changing anything other than text or non-relevant code formatting in questions.

Comment: @KenWhite I would normally agree, but since that edit was in the 5 minute grace period, it's ok as long as the OP wants it.

Comment: @bjb568: I disagree. I don't care if it was in a 3-second grace period; if the *original poster* didn't provide it, the edit is most certainly wrong. The code was not **part of the original poster's problem**, and was not provided by the person having that problem AFAICT. Editing questions is restricted for a very good reason; changing technical information (especially code itself) can change the entire problem. That 5-minute grace period belongs to **the original poster of the question**.

Comment: @KenWhite OP gets special edit privs. One of them is to approve with 1 vote. If OP approves, it's correct! (With restrictions - it's like voting)

Comment: @bjb568: No, OP can approve legitimate edits. Even if the OP approves the code added, it **still was not part of the problem** that the OP had, and should not be added by another editor. I don't care how many times you repeat it, if you're not the original poster of the question, **don't add code to the question**. It *changes the problem*. With the exception of formatting (and even then only if that formatting is not part of the problem itself), you should **not touch code in the question**, and that would mean **not adding code that didn't exist**. This discussion has been had here before.

Comment: @Ken So the edit has to be first rejected then directly applied by OP?

Comment: No, the edit should never have been made in the first place, because **it wasn't the OP's code**. The OP should have rejected it and done nothing else, because the code was **not posted by the OP** as part of the question. Look at the revision history - do you see any of that code in the original post, or in any version of it prior to it being added by Amir? I don't. I don't know how to say it any more clearly: **Do not edit questions and modify code other than to fix formatting**, and even formatting edits should only be done if the formatting is not relevant to the problem itself.

Comment: @KenWhite, since you haven't provided an answer, I take it you would roll-back such an edit, since it is very likely "defamation"?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Yes (and have). I leave a polite comment that explains that the edit was invalid and why, and roll back the edit.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a bold statement!