# Clarification for suggested edit rejection?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, edit-summary, specific-edit

It looks, from searching, that Meta is an okay place to ask this question; if not, I can delete it.

[Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5994258) in question. 1 accept, 3 reject.

The OP (me) asked a question and tagged both Clojure and Java bytecode. A brand-new user who had run into a similar error when dealing with a matrix in Java (but clearly had no experience in Clojure) gave a very brief explanation of how he had worked around the issue. If he doesn't know Clojure, he won't be able to give a precise explanation of how to do it in Clojure, but his solution to avoid the error translates directly, and it works. Because it was this user's first post, two reviewers came in with generic complaints that he hadn't addressed the OP. I wrote the OP. The relevance of his answer seemed pretty clear to me -- though it was quite obviously short on details.

So I took his idea, and applied it *clearly and directly* to the OP code that produced the error, and edited this code into his answer. I applied his idea to get the code, and yet the rejections all say, "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post."

In my most humble opinion, that's hogwash. I think my edit only *highlights* the original intent of the post, an intent that the new user could have made more clearly if he had had any experience with Clojure. I don't think the author of that post should be penalized for having an answer but not knowing how to implement it in your language. It's not friendly to new people, and I don't think it's not taking the "review" duties very seriously.

Am I wrong?

I have read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2472391), and unfortunately it only provides heuristics for editing code that already exists; I added a couple lines of code as an illustration of how the user's approach could be implemented in a language that user didn't know. One issue this answer *does* bring up is that I could have cleaned up his English just a little bit, but I didn't. If I gave a bad edit, perhaps the rejection messages should have been more clear? For instance, "This edit is incomplete." Because it doesn't seem like I "deviated from the intent of the post."

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: @gnat, there was no code in the original post. Your link provides no guidelines in this situation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: You were not wrong, but probably the reviewers overlooked all the details of the situation.  For example, the reviewers will not be shown that you are the original asker.  They have to go to the question directly.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261165/what-to-do-when-a-suspicious-but-potentially-useful-edit-appears

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Aye, though I'd argue that adding code to a question may require a little more telepathy than adding code to an answer. :)

Comment: No doubt about that; but I would have been *very* suspicious without comments from the OP of the answer that included the edited-in code. I can understand the rejection.

Comment: In this case, I think it might have been better to simply write another answer implementing it and reference his answer. You added enough material that it works as a new answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm gonna direct you to [an answer by psubsee2003 on a related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272976/are-edit-reviewers-forced-to-read-edit-comments/272985#272985):

> [image]
>   [image]

Whenever possible, *be detailed* in your revision notes - the more extensive they are, the more reviewers have to go on when trying to decide what you're doing... And *why* you're doing it.

It's also worth noting that edit reviewers don't see the comments on the post being edited, so if the purpose of your edit is revealed there, you'll want to summarize it in your edit summary as well. This is just a good idea in any case; there's no guarantee that comments will stick around, but revisions are a permanent record of what changed, as well as *why* it changed - but only if you take the time to make them so.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just need to learn how to use the system that is in place.