# Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6203618

So the previous approved edit added an erroneous comment, while not fixing the issue actually stated in the comments. This was approved, but when I explicitly state that this is erroneous and actually fix the redundancy in the code, it is rejected by 3 of 4 reviewers?

"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

How should I interpret this? What is wrong with my suggested edit?

Comment: Because editors cannot see that much context. To a reviewer, it looks like you are materially altering the code.

Comment: The previous edit should not have been approved either, I've rolled it back.

Comment: Hmm... Ok. So if I now would suggest to edit the completely redundant wrapping of the form variable in the end, would that be rejected? (As noted in the comments but misunderstood by the previous editor)

Comment: Chances are that it will, yes. Don't assume suggested edit reviewers actually fully understand jQuery and JavaScript. You can certainly *try*, with a good editing summary, but chances are it'll be rejected yes.

Comment: Instead, leave a comment on the answer informing the author and anyone else that will read about the issue.

Comment: I see that there is a [comment on the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery/10022098#comment37831078_10022098) that disputes your assertion that the line is not needed however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, that is in line with my proposed edit. This was what the previous editor misunderstod, and it is a part of the last line that is redundant.

Comment: Anyhow, it seems a little strange that issues like this would be hard to fix because the editors don't understand the language in question. Shouldn't they keep to audit things they understand, if this is not already the norm as you suggest?

Comment: Simple, gain 2k or more reputation and you don't have to rely on reviewers. By that time you'll hopefully have enough experience with the site to know when to edit and when not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you have any statistics on how many edits are suggested by <2k users and how many are made by >2k users? Just thinking about how significant this issue possibly might be for SO.

Comment: Very much related: [Shog's answer to Clarification for suggested edit rejection?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274454/250725).  In short, you can't trust the reviewers to always make the right decision so you should try to explain more in your edit comment.  Maybe you should have mentioned you were trying to rollback an incorrectly approved edit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, smart. So small seemingly insignificant edit => in-your-face motivation. Will try that.

Comment: @Alex: you could query the [Stack Overflow data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for details; today so far 2009 suggested edit reviews were made; that's about 600-700 suggested edits in 11 hours. You could manually add up the edits made this week by [looking at the top editors stats](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, we don't touch other peoples' codes. If there is something wrong with the answer you have a few options; If you wish to improve the code (*it's better to*) consider leaving a comment under the answer explaining what is wrong and why and how it should be improved. If the author of the answer agrees with you he will most likely improve his answer. If he doesn't, hopefully he will explain why...

If you can't comment then add your own answer and make sure you explain why your answer is the better one. Feel free to point out what is wrong with other approaches but remain constructive at all times.

People who review suggested edits are not always familiar with the technology the question is regarding. I may be a C# hero but be reviewing a suggested edit that modifies some JavaScript code. While the suggested edit may technically be correct, myself, as the reviewer wouldn't know -- I could hit SKIP but then I would probably have to skip A LOT of reviews if the system worked this way. I am supposed just say yeah, your edit improved the question ie: made things clear, improved tags or title, formatted code etc.

TL;DR

Generally, it's better to leave a comment if you spot something wrong with the code rather than edit the answer yourself. Let the OP workout what is wrong and fix it and if he is not willing consider adding your own answer.

Comment: I understand that it would be a mess if edits by members with low points were to easily approved. The answers should not be a scratch-board. But on the other hand, the strategy to comment and hope for the best doesn't seem to work in an optimal way either. (And kind of goes against the core philosophy on SE it that answers are editable and improved by all members.) So how about improving the system by letting the auditing take the tag-reputation in consideration when distributing edit-suggestions? Then users could edit answers more freely, because it would be reviews by the right people.

Comment: Alex, are you aware that reviewers can actually filter the review types by tag?

Comment: @Alex it's not a requirement but an option. General idea, like I said, is not to try to change code via suggested edits. If you have intentions to change the code it's almost always better to post your own answer and explain why it's better than the other. Any future visitor can see right away that there are more than 1 way to solve a problem and read why one is better.

Comment: Oups, now you answered while I was messing around with my comment... "No. So why don't they?". Well ok, I hear you. I'm satisfied here, but still suspecting that it would/could be better to make the tag-filter mandatory and automatic, and keep the comments as comments and the answer as good as possible.

Comment: And as well recognising that the situation where code in an answer might be plain wrong or redundant, and the situation where there might be different approaches to an answer, are two different things.

Comment: When an answer is plain wrong we just downvote. If it's not an answer we flag as such. When an answer need improvement we leave a comment :)

Comment: "When an answer need improvement we leave a comment" Really? Isn't that like totally against the idea of this platform?

Comment: No. Can you explain why would that be? Comments are there to request clarification. If you think a code needs clarification - leave a comment asking *why ...*

Comment: I don't see that "request clarification" and "need improvement" are synonyms. As far as I know, the special thing with SO was that answers are not own by a single user and both can and should be improved by everyone that are able to. This wiki-format is what I perceive as the big thing about SO, so to hear that you should try to inject improvements (or correct plain errors) by comments and hope that the original answerer picks it up, that goes against the idea of SO for me.

Comment: but according to your philosophy we would always and only have 1 single answer to each answered question improved by the community multiple times...

Comment: No, as I said I think there is a difference between erroneous/dirty code and different approaches to a solution.

Comment: Of course there is.. I am not trying to throw that in the same box. But when something is plain wrong we downvote to express disagreement.

Comment: So how about if the answer in general is good, but contains some rust and dirt here and there? We should not try to clean that up directly?

Comment: I would say it depends on the views, if there are any more up to date duplicate questions, how old the answer is and if it still applies within todays technology standards etc.. sometimes the comment you leave when suggesting an edit is enough to explain why an answer should be updated and justifies it well enough for the reviewers to accept such an edit. I would say those are rather exceptions.